# Enable cloudwatch logs with ebextensions - SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

To enable cloudwatch logs for my Springboot application which is deployed with Beanstalk, I added `.ebextensions` directory and added `variables.config` file in this directory with following content:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:healthreporting:system
    option_name: SystemType
    value: enhanced
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs:health
    option_name: HealthStreamingEnabled
    value: true
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:cloudwatch:logs
    option_name: StreamLogs
    value: true
```

And I placed this `.ebextensions` folder in the directory where my application jar file exists. So, finally my zip contains target folder with application jar file and `.ebextensions` directory. When I upload this zip file, application is working, but logs are not enabled. Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: .extensions needs to be on the same level as your src and .elasticbeanstalk folders.